# asynchronous updates to UI from backend

Tags: java

I am dealing with a project where I have a java process. This process updates my backend database tables every few hours.
Everytime a table update is done i need to refresh my UI . My UI is a simple jsp with html table which contains the data from database tables.

Any idea how i can do that? I use java.util.concurrent package in my project. As i understand this is more like a asynchronous push process.
Any ideas will be apprecaited.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help you to [Implementing an Asynchronous Service Initiation with Dynamic UI Update](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28271_01/fusionapps.1111/e15524/uc_async_dynamic.htm)

Comment: really? I am not looking for such a complicated solution. Looking for something simple...thanks.